# Закрытия массива потоков

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность

Мне необходимо создать приложение, в котором происходит перемножение двух квадратных матриц. При этом пользователю предоставляется сделать выбор количества потоков, в которых будет происходить это самое умножение (maxThreadCount = matrixSize).
В  связи с этим приложение имеет 2 класса:

1. `my_thread : public QObject` - здесь реализована функция перемножения
2. `MainWindow` - GUI

Запуск потоков происходит так:

```
for (qint32 i=0; i < threads_count; ++i)
    {
        myClassArray[i].moveToThread(&thrArray[i]);
        thrArray[i].start();
        QObject::connect(&thrArray[i], SIGNAL(started()), &myClassArray[i], SLOT(calculatingFirstAndLastIndeces()));
    }
```

Где, после перемножения в классе `my_thread`, посылается сигнал об окончании перемножения:

```
emit end_work(numberThisThread);
```

Но обработка:

```
void MainWindow::rcvEndWork(qint32 threadNumber)
{
    thrArray[threadNumber].quit();
    qDebug() << "Threads №" << threadNumber << " were closed";
}
```

этого сигнала в `MainWindow` происходит лишь один раз, т.е. если сигнал будет послан из 1600 потоков, то закроется лишь один.

Как мне закрыть все потоки после того, как они закончили свою работу?

Comment: Не проще ли `#pragma omp parallel for`?

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Мне необходимо изучить библиотеку Qt, поэтому только так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема найдена. Заключается она в строчке

```
connect(myClassArray, &my_thread::end_work, this, &MainWindow::rcvEndWork );
```

Суть в том, что при использовании **myClassArray** в качестве параметра мы обращаемся к первому элементу массива (т.к. это указатель)

```
my_thread *myClassArray;
myClassArray = new my_thread [threads_count];
```

Тогда `connect(...)` приобретает следующий вид:

```
for (qint32 i=0; i < threads_count; ++i)
        connect(&myClassArray[i], &my_thread::end_work, this, &MainWindow::rcvEndWork );
```

В результате всё работает как надо

```
void MainWindow::rcvEndWork(quint16 threadNumber)
{
    qDebug() << "Aloha" << threadNumber;
    thrArray[threadNumber].quit();
    thrArray[threadNumber].wait();
    ++finishCount;
    if (finishCount == threads_count)
        qDebug() << "Time passed" << timer->elapsed();
}
```